# Registration page, Toast and Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-toast

I have a problem with my registration page with firebase but in particular with the Toast. I use the firebase database. 
With my registration page I put user's data in my database but if the username is equal to another in the database, the application shows me a toast ("Username is already registered, try again") and it's ok. 
When I register with a new username the toast shows me "Registration Success" and then I see a series of toasts which say this: "Username is already registered, try again". 
I think that the problem is very easy but I don't know the solution. 
Thank you in advance.

[image]

**Registration.java:**

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ET_USER_LOCATION, ET_USER_MAIL, ET_USER_NAME, ET_USER_PASS;
String user_location, user_mail, user_name, user_pass, user_bitmapImage = "NoImage";
Button registerButton;
Context mContext;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference users = database.getReference("Users").child("UserApp");
String key = users.child("UserApp").push().getKey();
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    mContext = this;

    ET_USER_LOCATION = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_location);
    ET_USER_MAIL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_mail);
    ET_USER_NAME = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
    ET_USER_PASS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);

    registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user_location = ET_USER_LOCATION.getText().toString();
            user_mail = ET_USER_MAIL.getText().toString();
            user_name = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
            user_pass = ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();

            users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String result = registerWithoutRepetition(dataSnapshot);
                    if(Objects.equals(result, "Username is already registered, try again")){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if(Objects.equals(result, "Registration Success")){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private String registerWithoutRepetition(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    String result;
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        UserApp userApp = snapshot.getValue(UserApp.class);
        if (Objects.equals(userApp.user_name, user_name)) {
            result = "Username is already registered, try again";
            return result;
        }
    }
    writeNewUser(key, user_name, user_mail, user_pass, user_location, token, user_bitmapImage);
    result = "Registration Success";
    return result;
}


private void writeNewUser(String user_id, String user_name, String user_mail, String user_pass,
                          String user_location, String user_token, String user_bitmapImage) {
    UserApp user = new UserApp(user_name, user_mail, user_pass, user_location, user_token, user_bitmapImage);

    users.child(user_id).setValue(user);
}
```

Comment: After you register a listener with `addValueEventListener()` it will fire *every time* something changes in the users node. You're probably only interested in a single event, in which case you can [use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#read_data_once).

Comment: I have tried before with a listener but nothing and now it works. Thank you very much frank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you register a listener with addValueEventListener() it will fire every time something changes in the users node.

You're probably only interested in a single event, in which case you can [use addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#read_data_once).